# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token when using leaflet with flask

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've added all required scripts, config.js which has my API_KEY however it is keep on telling me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." I've checked my api key multiple times and it seems to be correct.

This is my python file

```
app.route("/")
def index():
    """Return the homepage."""
    return render_template("index.html", cities=cities, aqi=aqi, CO=CO, NO2=NO2, SO2=SO2, PM25=pm25)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

cities, aqi,etc... are lists that I am sending to index.html

index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Air-Quality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.2/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css"></script>

    <!-- My on scrape for lists -->

    <!-- Sending lists to JS from python -->
    <script>
        var cities = {{cities|tojson}};
        var aqi = {{aqi|tojson}};
        var CO = {{CO|tojson}};
        var NO2 = {{NO2|tojson}};
        var SO2 = {{SO2|tojson}};
        var PM25 = {{PM25|tojson}};
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center main globe">
    </div>
```

and javascript code that is calling leaflet

```
var myMap = L.map('globe', {
    center:[45.5017, -73.5673],
    zoom:1
});

L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: "mapbox.streets-basic",
  accessToken: API_KEY
}).addTo(myMap);
```

file paths are all correct. I am very curious about what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

full error:

```
leaflet.css:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Map container not found.
    at i._initContainer (leaflet.js:5)
    at initialize (leaflet.js:5)
    at new i (leaflet.js:5)
    at Object.t.map (leaflet.js:5)
    at draw_globe.js:3
```

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace.

Comment: from my understanding stack trace it full error message. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the errors. It says the unexpected token occurs in `leaflet.css` on line 3. The issue here is that you're trying to load a CSS file as javascript. That isn't going to work. You need to indicate a stylesheet with a `<link>` tag. So instead of:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css"></script>
```

You should do:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css">
```

Note that the URL ends with `.css` instead of `.js` (which is why you need to include it this way). Things ending with `.js` should be included using `<script>` tags as you did with

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.2/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh so all css are connected with link tag and js with script tag?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can also `@import` from within CSS to import a CSS file, but just stick to using `<link>`.